# Any good idea/ best practice for maintaining local patches for open source repo?

Tags: git, github, merge, open-source, maintainability

we have a repo for our customers and using some open source software (50+ repos), and for the long time development and maintenance, there being many local modifications that are so customised and could not go to the upstream (those repo also needed to upgrade and merge the security CLs in time).

For now we have using two ways to maintenance, both have advantage and disadvantages:

1. Just push the local patches to the local branch, and merge the new version if needed.(the upgrade is hard and the commit history is ugly,and the conflict solving commit contains mixed code for different commits. But easier for daily development)
2. Keep clean patch lists in each repo and merge when build ( the patch list maintenance is not easy for everyone in team, and it's not convenient to view the code in daily development, but it's clean to know/check the local fix, also easier to debug)

I also consider of a way that create new local repos and rebase the patch, but the del/add repo way is ugly and the local codebase are conflicted.

Does someone have a best practice on keeping local branch and good way for maintaining ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this matters, but are you aware that git doesn't track patches? Each commit is a snapshot of the _whole repo_.

Comment: yes, each git commit is a snapshot，but we have to maintain both growing local patches and upgrade the opensource repos at the same time.  we are currently using the merge way, but  since the upstream upgraded , the local commit always have a lot conflicts，and the merge commit itself always contain many conflict resolved code from many local patches，which means the "snapshot " is not the newest patch, image someone add a feature 2 year ago and it have some issue now, the related commit is not the newest status :( .